# API Soap v2 problem with encoding

Tags: soap-api-v2, character-encoding

I'm having problems with encoding, my store is so configured:

[image]

And in my php code:

```
$client = new SoapClient($url, array('trace' => 1, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8'));
$session_id = $client->login($username, $password);
$result = $client->customerCustomerList($session_id);
var_dump($result);
```

But the customer's name is with character problems:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is working correctly. However the `var_dump` seems to produce output which is displayed by your browser not using UTF-8 encoding.

You can try adding `header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');` before your `var_dump` or an `echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';`

Comment: @MateusVitali that's great - feel free to mark this answer as the accepted solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure PHP is using the correct encoding: [mb_internal_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php)